# Error: android.view.InflateException - googlemaps (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I'am new in kotlin and android studio. The problem comes I try to push a button "GPS" from "MainActivity" to  "GpsView" (it's other activity);here you can see a map like googleMap, but I try run and push the button and I have **Error: android.view.InflateException**.

I don't konw how fix this error.

In Build.gradle -> dependencies, I paste this
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'`

In AndroidManifest add this

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

the code of MainActivity :

```
package com.eleczero.hellokotlin

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun buttongps(view:View){
        val intent = Intent(this,GpsView::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

the layout of the MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btngps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttongps"
        android:text="GPS"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="323dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The GpsView code is

```
package com.eleczero.hellokotlin

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

class GpsView : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {//

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_view)
        createFracment()
    }

    private fun createFracment() {
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
    }
```

the layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```